# Maintain a separate branch for each platform

Tags: c, git, cross-platform, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to port my project to another platform and I've found a few differences between this new platform and the one I started on. I've seen the autotools package and configure scripts which are supposed to help with that, but I was wondering how feasible it would be to just have a separate branch for each new platform.

The only problem I see is how to do development on the target platform and then merge in changes to other branches without getting the platform-dependent changes. If there is a way to do that, it seems to me it'd be much cleaner.

Has anyone done this who can recommend/discourage this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branching to work out compatibility for a target platform is doable. Just be sure to separate out changes that don't have to do with the target platform specifically into another branch.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely discourage that approach.

You're just asking for trouble if you keep the same code in branches that can't be merged.  It's going to be incredibly confusing to keep track of what changes have been applied to what branches and a nightmare should you forget to apply a change to one of your platform branches.

You didn't mention the language, but use the features available in the language to separate code differences between platforms, but using one branch.  For example, in C++, you should first use file-based separation.  For example, if you have sound code for Mac, Linux and Windows platforms, create a sound_mac.cpp, sound_windows.cpp and sound_linux.cpp file, each containing the same classes and methods, but containing very different platform-specific implementations.  Obviously, you only add the appropriate file to the IDE on the particular platform.  So, your Xcode project gets sound_mac.cpp file, while your Visual Studio project uses the sound_windows.cpp file.  The files which reference those classes and methods will use #ifdef's to determine which headers to include.

You'll use a similar approach for things like installer scripts.  You may have a different installer on the Mac than on Windows, but the files for both will be in the branch.  Your build script on the Mac will simply utilize the Mac-specific installer files and ignore the Windows-specific files.

Keeping things in one branch and just ignoring what doesn't apply to the current platform allows you merge back and forth between topic branches and the master, making your life much more sane.

Comment: What if I didn't merge the platform-branch? I would have to deal with changes that affected differences between platforms anyway, doing what I propose would only change the place where I had to deal with it.

Comment: If you make a change on one platform branch that affects all platforms, you're going to have to merge that change to all platform branches. You can do what you want, but you're going to have to ensure that you have one branch for common code, and then platform-specific branches only contain platform-specific additions.  You'll only be able to merge from common code into the platform-specific branches, never the other direction.  It can be done, but I think maintaining a codebase that can be freely merged between branches is a better plan.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer, or creating another answer if you feel this answer doesn't solve the problem.  If you don't accept answers, people are not going to be incented to help.